# Read data from an html input without id and without name

Tags: html, google-chrome, dom, input, element

I have an html page with a table that contains several inputs.I want to take the data from the inputs, however they do not have id or name.

If I analyze the DOM I can see that each input has different properties. It has a property $H: 2029 and a tkPid:"554". Is there a way to read through these properties?
[image: DevTools screenshot]

The code of the input is the following:

[image: input screen copy]

If I check 'tkPid' property exists as a non-regular attribute:

```
 let input = document.querySelector('input');
  input.hasAttribute('tkPid');  \\ Response: false
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Are you saying that each `input` that you're interested in has `$H: 2029` and a `tkPid:"554"`? Also, I take it you are webscraping?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Each entry has a different $H and tkPid.
Yes, web scraping

Comment: OK, And elements that you are not interested in do not have these properties?

Comment: No. They do not have these properties

Comment: I think you will need to show a sample url. The problem I think you will have is that those properties are not part of the markup. As such, if you just pull in the html and scrape it, those properties won't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Finally he was able to read and treat the described properties as follows:

```
 document.getElementsByClassName('v-textfield v-widget align-right v-textfield-align-right v-has-width v-has-height')[3].tkPid /// Result: 554
```

Thanks for your interest #Lee Taylor